# Nginx load static files for multiple locations

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, location, static-files

I have multiples locations in a nginx .conf file, like this.

```
server {
    ...

    location /api/ {
            client_max_body_size 0;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_read_timeout 5m;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X­Forwarded­For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    ...

    location /cliente/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }

   location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

In most cases the locations are node servers that serve his own statics files and api rest.

The static files in every node app is loading in use html file and call as follow

```
/my-static-path-1/
/my-static-path-2/
```

**The problem:**

When the server try to load a path this is loading directly from `/` and no using the own sub path, causing 404 erros.

**Example:**

1) The url `http:/myip_sample.com/cliente` call a nodejs app thar serve a html file, this file require load a css script like `/my-static-path/js/sample.js`.

2) This file call `http:/myip_sample.com/my-static-path/js/sample.js` instead http:/myip_sample.com/**cliente**/my-static-path/js/sample.js

I want do this without changing anything, only use nginx conf file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can serve static from its own location /my-static-path-1/ { root /var/static/;} http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/

Answer (score 0):

use this for each assets folder location you do have

```
location /my-static-path-1 {
        alias /location/to/my-static-path-1;
    }

location /my-static-path-2 {
        alias /location/to/my-static-path-2;
    }
```